# Jest - test if one function called the other

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a class that contains a few static functions. Let's call that class allFunctions. allFunctions.makeChanges(a,b,c) calls allFunctions.callUpdate().

None of these functions return any value. Both of them simply modify some arguments and call a function providing with them.

```
export class allFunctions {

    public static makeChanges(a, b, c) {
        ...
        this.callUpdate(c, d);
    }

    public static callUpdate(c, d) {
        otherFunctions.makeUpdate();
    }

}
```

I want to test when function makeChanges() is called if callUpdate() function happens to be called as well.

I tried something like this:

```
import { allFunctions } from '../allFunctions';

describe('simple test', () => {

    it('makeChanges() should call callUpdate()', () => {

        const a = 1, b = 2, ...;

        allFunctions.callUpdate = jest.fn();

        const result = allFunctions.makeChanges(a,b,c);

        expect(allFunctions.callUpdate).toBeCalled();

    });

});
```

Sadly, this does not work. Is it possible to test if one functions calls the other one? If so, what would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the solution. I needed to use spy instead of jest.fn();

The solution looks like this:

```
import { allFunctions } from '../allFunctions';

describe('simple test', () => {

    it('makeChanges() should call callUpdate()', () => {

        const a = 1, b = 2, ...;

        const spy = jest.spyOn(allFunctions, 'callUpdate');

        allFunctions.makeChanges(a,b,c);

        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to all all find except the use of word public in the class. Remove them.

```js
export class allFunctions {

    static makeChanges(a, b, c) {
        ...
        this.callUpdate(c, d);
    }

    static callUpdate(c, d) {
        otherFunctions.makeUpdate();
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for the notice but sadly I cannot remove 'public' since due to my typescript configurations it needs to be either public, private or protected and only the public one fits my needs in this place.